# Can't get rid of crosshair (place new item) cursor in Visual Studio 2010 xaml editor

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I'm inside a XAML page, in the Design screen. Somehow I got VS2010 into a mode where it changes the cursor to crosshairs, and when you click you place a UIElement where you clicked.  **I can't figure out a) how I got into this mode in the first place, and b) how to get out.**  I like to be able to click on elements in the Design view and automatically navigate to the XAML associated with it, and I can't get back into that mode.

Any ideas?

PS- I'm in Visual Studio Express 2010 for C#, if that makes any difference.

Comment: There should be a toolbox on the left of VS. The top item in the toolbox should be a mouse cursor arrow. Click it.

Comment: I see no such mouse cursor arrow- that may be my problem.  Which toolbox do you refer to?

Comment: The real question is, how do I make the Visual Studio 2010 XAML editor usable?

Comment: I'm using VS 2010 Professional, but I _can't_ imagine that your version doesn't have a Toolbox. Is it docked on the far-left side of the VS window? There may be a sideways button that says Toolbox, if so. If not, select Edit from the menu and then select Toolbox to see if that works. (Also, the arrow to which I'm referring says "Pointer", by the way.)

Comment: @Steve If you're not kidding, what problems are you having with it? (Not that comments is the best place to answer your question, but if we find a question in there, maybe you could ask it and then someone here could answer it for you.)

Comment: @Todd: I have a Toolbox.  It has the following sections: {myProgramName} WPF user controls, {myProgramName} Controls, Common WPF Controls, All Windows forms Controls, ... Printing, ... WPF InterOperability... etc.  It doesn't have a section with the "Pointer", though I think I remember seeing it there once

Comment: It should be at the very top of the list. You may have to scroll up (or, if "All Windows Forms Controls" is closed, click the triangular arrow to open it; the top item should be Pointer).

Comment: That's a good idea Michael.  No I'm not kidding.  The performance of the XAML editor is the worst part of my day!

Comment: @Todd: Ok, I finally figured it out- I had to right click on the toolbox and select "Reset Toolbox".  Then I found the "Pointer" item.  Really odd.  I didn't intentionally edit the ToolBox's settings to re-arrange it.  Thanks!

Comment: Then add your comment as an answer and accept it (I think it might be a day or two before you can accept your own answer, though; the system errs on the side of letting _others_ answer the question, even if you were able to answer it yourself). That'll help others in the future who may encounter this problem.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out, thanks to Michael Todd.  Here is the answer:

The ToolBox usually holds a button for the standard Pointer, which gets you out of the mode I mentioned above.  However, if you have edited the display options on the ToolBox, then it may be buried or (possibly?) not visible at all.  To fix this, right click on any item in the ToolBox window and select "Reset Toolbox" from the popup menu.  The "Pointer" option should now be at the top of the list, under almost every section.

Comment: Thx, got me too :))) .. I love SF!

Comment: Thanks ... this helped me out today. +1 for your question and answer.

Comment: U saved my day too.. :) +1